# Ordering elements in a dropdown based on a property of the object

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have an array containing objects. I fill a dropdown using the array. How can the elements in the dropdown be arranged based a property of the object say ID?

The array has 3 elements (read objects at indexes 0,1, and 2). I want to rearrange my dropdown based on a property of the object in the array, say ID (which is 3,1 and 2 respectively).

Currently even if I bind the dropdown with sorted array, it is a futile effort, as the dropdown is indexed based on the name of the property.

```
_data.push(objItem[i]); 
// here the array is being populated with data after it has been populated, I'm filling a dropdown using
 System.Utils.fillSelectData("$selectDDL", _data, "FieldValue", "FieldText");
//our framework supports this code But every time the binding is being done based on FieldText..
```

Any insight would be highly obliged..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'dropdown'? An HTML select element? Do you use a jQuery plugin?

Comment: And which plugin is it? :)  (A link would be most useful)

Comment: i m sorry...its an html select actually...extremely sorry about that first information...

Comment: In that case the options should appear exactly in the order you added them to the DOM. Please expand the question with some code that produces the problem.

Comment: _data.push(objItem[i]); // here the array is being populated with data

After it has been populated, im filling a dropdown using

System.Utils.fillSelectData("$selectDDL", _data, "FieldValue", "FieldText"); //our framework supports this code

But every time the binding is being done based on FieldText..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ordering objects by id example:

```
    var employees=[]
        employees[0]={id: 1, name:"George", age:32}
        employees[1]={id: 4, name:"Edward", age:17}
        employees[2]={id: 2, name:"Christine", age:58}
        employees[3]={id: 3, name:"Sarah", age:62}

    var sorted = employees.sort(function(a, b) {
       return a.id-b.id 
    });

    for(var i=0;i<sorted.length;i++) {
       alert(sorted[i].id); 
    }
```

Comment: I tried this.The array is sorted but on after binding it is listed as before based on textValue. :(

Answer (score 0):

If `fillSelectData` of your framework doesn't have an optional parameter for the sorting key, then you can (1) extend it with such, or (2) fill the select element maually, avoiding this method completely.

Comment: thanks abesto...sorry for an unreasonably delayed reply...i used it from my available framework.

Answer (score -1):

Could you post some codee? :)

SEE Example 2:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

```
function sortNumber(a,b)
{
return a - b;
}

var n = ["10", "5", "40", "25", "100", "1"];
document.write(n.sort(sortNumber));
```